# Using VBA to identify ranges based on specific values

Tags: excel, vba

This is my first post and I'm kind of a beginner; please be gentle. See [this link](https://imgur.com/gallery/kU0MMpm) for a reference of the sheet I'm working with.

My plan is to have B2 contain a drop-down list that will be used to selectively collapse certain row groups to just their heading. I've figured out how to collapse one group with this:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim KeyCells As Range

    Set KeyCells = Range("B1")

    If Not Application.Intersect(KeyCells, Range(Target.Address)) _
        Is Nothing Then

       If Range("B1") = "All" Then
            Rows("3:6").Select
            Selection.EntireRow.Hidden = False
            Range("B1").Select
       Else
            Rows("3:6").Select
            Selection.EntireRow.Hidden = True
            Range("B1").Select
       End If

    End If

End Sub
```

What I don't have is a way to automatically find the groups. If I use a range like Rows("3:6") and someone adds/removes a row, it won't work. (right?)

What I *think* I need is a way to identify the required ranges by looking at information in the headers. The reference example is blank, but at the "A" column of each grey row will be a number (100, 101, 150, 380, 420A, 420B, 420C, 890). No number will appear twice, and they will appear in numerical order. The "A" column in the white cells under the gray headers will all be blank.

Is there VBA code that will find the locations of the unique headers so I can use their locations to collapse specific groups?

Additional edit to add new screenshots of what I'm hoping to achieve. Person X, Y, Z all have their predetermined grouping they want expanded or collapsed. And I'd probably add an "all" and "none" if I can figure it out. They'll give me that in advance. The numbers on the left won't ever change. It's only a question of whether Person X wants group 120 expanded or collapsed. https://imgur.com/c2lNujn

Edit to show current code:

```
Public HeaderColor As Long


Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    Me.HeaderColor = RGB(217, 217, 217)

    'If A1 is true, group rows
    If Range("A1").Value Then
        'Use getRegion function on target
        Dim rng As Range
        Set rng = getRegion(Target)

        'If the returned range is nothing then end sub
        If rng Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

        'Select region
        Application.EnableEvents = False
            rng.Select
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    End If

    'If D1 is true, apply Y/N options for selection in C1
    If Range("D1").Value Then

    Dim rngX As Range, c As Range
    Set rngX = Worksheets("Options").Range("A1:N1").Find(Range("C1"), lookat:=xlPart)

    If Not rngX Is Nothing Then
        'MsgBox Chr(34) & Range("C1").Value & Chr(34) & " found at " & rngX.Address
    End If

'Check
'    Dim groupcounter As Long
'    For groupcounter = 1 To 80
'        If Worksheets("Options").Range(rngX.Column, groupcounter + 1) = "Y" Then
'            getNthRegion(ActiveSheet, groupcounter).Hidden = True
'        ElseIf Worksheets("Options").Range(rng.Column, groupcounter + 1) = "N" Then
'            getNthRegion(ActiveSheet, groupcounter).Hidden = False
'        End If
'    Next groupcounter
End If


End Sub
Sub customiseVisibility(ByVal query As String)
    Dim cell As Range
    Set cell = OptionsSheet.Range("1:1").Find(query)
    Dim offset As Long
    offset = 1
    While Not IsEmpty(cell.offset(offset))
        getNthRegion(MySheet, offset).Hidden = cell.offset(offset).Value = "N"
        offset = offset + 1
    Wend
End Sub

Private Function getRegion(cell As Range) As Range
    Dim formatted As Boolean
    Dim cell_start, cell_end As Range

    'If cell row is 1 then exit function
    If cell.Row <= 1 Then Exit Function

    'If cell row count > 1 then use first cell selected
    If cell.Rows.Count > 1 Then Set cell = cell.Cells(1, 1)

    'If selection is outside of used range, do nothing
    If Application.Intersect(cell, cell.Parent.UsedRange) Is Nothing Then Exit Function

    'Special condition
    If cell.Interior.Color = Me.HeaderColor Then
        'Select row below
        Set cell = cell.offset(1)
    End If

    'Get start cell
    Set cell_start = cell
    While Not cell_start.Interior.Color = Me.HeaderColor And Not Application.Intersect(cell_start, cell.Parent.UsedRange) Is Nothing ' Your gray color
        Set cell_start = cell_start.offset(-1)
    Wend

    'Get end cell
    Set cell_end = cell
    While Not cell_end.offset(iRowEnd, 0).Interior.Color = Me.HeaderColor And Not Application.Intersect(cell_end, cell.Parent.UsedRange) Is Nothing ' Your gray color
        Set cell_end = cell_end.offset(1)
    Wend

    'Get region
    Set getRegion = Range(cell_start.offset(1), cell_end.offset(-1)).EntireRow
End Function

Function getNthRegion(ByVal sheet As Worksheet, ByVal n As Long) As Range
    Dim i, counter As Long
    For i = 1 To sheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
       If sheet.Cells(i, 1).Interior.Color = HeaderColor Then
          counter = counter + 1
       End If
       If counter = n Then
           Set getNthRegion = getRegion(sheet.Cells(i, 1))
           Exit Function
       End If
    Next
End Function
```

Comment: Use [`Range.Find`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.find).

Comment: Will column A contain anything else except for for those identifiers? - `420A` won't be treated as a number.

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook Column A won't have anything except the identifiers. And it would be OK if 420A were ignored, as I would want all of that to roll up into the 420 group header anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you abuse your formatting?

Here is tested code:

```
Public  HeaderColor  as Long
Private OptionsSheet as Worksheet
Private DataSheet    as Worksheet

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
  Me.HeaderColor = RGB(217, 217, 217)
  set OptionsSheet = sheets("Options")
  set DataSheet = ActiveWorksheet

  if target.address = "$B$1" then
    customiseVisibility target.value
  end if
End Sub

Sub customiseVisibility(ByVal query As String)
  Dim cell As Range
  Set cell = OptionsSheet.Range("1:1").Find(query)
  Dim offset As Long
  offset = 1
  While Not IsEmpty(cell.offset(offset))
    getNthRegion(DataSheet, offset).Hidden = cell.offset(offset).Value = "N"
    offset = offset + 1
  Wend
End Sub
Private Function getRegion(cell As Range) As Range
    Dim formatted As Boolean
    Dim cell_start, cell_end As Range

    'If cell row is 1 then exit function
    If cell.Row <= 1 Then Exit Function

    'If cell row count > 1 then use first cell selected
    If cell.Rows.Count > 1 Then Set cell = cell.Cells(1, 1)

    'If selection is outside of used range, do nothing
    If Application.Intersect(cell, cell.Parent.UsedRange) Is Nothing Then Exit Function

    'Special condition
    If cell.Interior.Color = Me.HeaderColor Then
        'Select row below
        Set cell = cell.offset(1)
    End If

    'Get start cell
    Set cell_start = cell
    While Not cell_start.Interior.Color = Me.HeaderColor And Not Application.Intersect(cell_start, cell.Parent.UsedRange) Is Nothing ' Your gray color
        Set cell_start = cell_start.offset(-1)
    Wend

    'Get end cell
    Set cell_end = cell
    While Not cell_end.offset(iRowEnd, 0).Interior.Color = Me.HeaderColor And Not Application.Intersect(cell_end, cell.Parent.UsedRange) Is Nothing ' Your gray color
        Set cell_end = cell_end.offset(1)
    Wend

    'Get region
    Set getRegion = Range(cell_start.offset(1), cell_end.offset(-1)).EntireRow
End Function
Function getNthRegion(ByVal sheet As Worksheet, ByVal n As Long) As Range
    Dim i, counter As Long
    For i = 1 To sheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
       If sheet.Cells(i, 1).Interior.Color = HeaderColor Then
          counter = counter + 1
       End If
       If counter = n Then
           Set getNthRegion = getRegion(sheet.Cells(i, 1))
           Exit Function
       End If
    Next
End Function
```

**Note:**

This question is really really specific. Next time try to break your problem down into smaller chunks and take on 1 question at a time (if anything). Also I strongly recommend including example data to work off of. E.G.

```
| Number | All | PersonA | PersonB | ...
-----------------------------------------
|   1    |  N  |    Y    |    N    | ...
|   2    |  N  |    Y    |    N    | ...
|   3    |  N  |    Y    |    N    | ...
|   4    |  N  |    Y    |    Y    | ...
|   5    |  N  |    N    |    N    | ...
|   6    |  N  |    N    |    Y    | ...
|   7    |  N  |    N    |    N    | ...
|   8    |  N  |    N    |    Y    | ...
```

Comment: Sancarn, is that all based on a selected cell? Is it possible to identify all the groups by that coloring without knowing which cell is selected and just hide the group by number? The groups I'm working with are consistent, so I could theoretically hide the 22nd group if I know a user won't care about it.

Comment: It is all based on the cell given to the `getRegion` function defined above. You can of course reverse engineer it to hide the nth group indeed. A simple way would be to loop through all rows, and get the address of getRegion() function. Count the unique addresses and you have god the nth group. :)

Comment: What would that look like, to loop through the rows and get the unique addresses to hide, say the 2nd, 4th and 6th groups?

Comment: @ClaudioIbarra See the added code for `getNthRegion()` :). Untested but be something like that.

Comment: I got your demo to work on mine (it took me a while to figure out the color I had was 217,217,217 and not 200,200,200 but once I got that it started to work like yours). Could you explain how the getNthRegion might work for me? It feels promising.

Comment: Hiding the 22nd group:  `getNthRegion(ActiveSheet,22).hidden=true`

Comment: you have been such a help!! I feel like I'm so close to exactly what I had in mind. If I had a cell at the top with a list pointing to the column headers on an "Options" sheet (like this https://imgur.com/gallery/IzZhyzX), would it be possible to define which groups get hidden that way? So if I select Person B in the cell at the top, groups 11-18 collapse and if I choose Person A, groups 6-10 collapse? Would that be a sub, or a function?

Comment: See the edit :) This is far from the most efficient solution, but it'll work. It'd be more efficient to loop through all the cells of MySheet, figure out the offset, then call `getRegion()` for each. But hopefully it won't matter a great deal...

Comment: I've edited the bottom of the post to include all the code currently in play. I must have something wrong. the customisevisibility sub never gets called. The commented section where I butchered the groupcounter use -- I know I have the syntax wrong, but does what I was trying to do come through?

Comment: Haha yes indeed. the `CustomiseVisibility` sub is never called in the code I provided. [It's your job to call it how you want to](https://www.guru99.com/vba-functions-subroutine.html). And you'll want to change `MySheet` variable within the subroutine also.

Comment: [Something like this](https://gist.github.com/sancarn/6657b2a09b79459fd47bcdaabc558642)

Comment: I know it's bad form to have an extended discussion in the comments. I apologize I don't have enough account points to move this into chat. I get an error at the 'Set DataSheet = ActiveWorksheet' line. A mouseover on ActiveWorksheet tells me it's Empty and the same on DataSheet reveals it equals Nothing. Do I change that to be 'Sheets("[name of main worksheet]")' ?

Comment: "Do I change that to be 'Sheets("[name of main worksheet]")' ?" >>> Yup. And my mistake. That should be `ActiveSheet` or theoretically it could be `Me` depending on where you are putting this code... But putting `Sheets("[name of main worksheet]")` will work fine also :)

Comment: That did it!! That did it! That runs exactly what I was hoping to accomplish. Now the hopefully easiest part -- crediting with answers. Can you update your answer to that code?

Comment: @ClaudioIbarra Edited the answer. Also read the notes and you might want to reword the question a bit better.

Answer (score 0):

As @BigBen suggested - use `FIND` and then Group between the headers - one row down from Start and one row up from End.

```
Public Sub CreateOutline()

    Dim sFirstAdd As String
    Dim rFound As Range
    Dim rStart As Range
    Dim rEnd As Range

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

        .Cells.ClearOutline 'Remove any existing.

        With .Cells.EntireColumn
            Set rFound = .Find(What:="*", _
                               After:=.Cells(1, 1), _
                               LookIn:=xlValues, _
                               SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                               SearchDirection:=xlNext)

            If Not rFound Is Nothing Then
                sFirstAdd = rFound.Address
                Do
                    Set rStart = rFound
                    Set rFound = .FindNext(rFound)
                    Set rEnd = rFound

                    Range(rStart.Offset(1), rEnd.Offset(-1)).Rows.Group

                    'Include a marker to state where the end of the last section is.
                    'Otherwise the last section will go from cell A1 to just below last section header.
                    If rEnd = "End" Then sFirstAdd = rFound.Address

                Loop While rFound.Address <> sFirstAdd
            End If

        End With
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: I'm trying to figure out where I went wrong. After I changed "Sheet1" to the name of the worksheet, I did get an error at the Range(rStart.Offset(1), rEnd.Offset(-1)).Rows.Group line, but I imagine that's because I didn't properly set an end marker. What also happened was the groupings I originally setup disappeared. Is it possible to keep them?

Comment: Not at my computer at the moment so can't test why you're getting an error.  The `ClearOutline`line removes any existing groups. You'll have to figure out how to test if a grouping already exists to retain previous groups so the code doesn't add rhem again.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of hiding and unhiding rows, you can use the [`Outline.ShowLevels`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.outline.showlevels) method to collapse the grouping.

So something like this to:

- Test if `B1` changed.
- [`Find`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.find) the corresponding header in the first column.
- If there's a match, test if the next row has a grouping (`OutlineLevel > 1`).
- If so, `ShowDetail = False` for that row.

Note that the use of `On Error Resume Next` is discouraged. However `.ShowDetail = False` threw an error when the specified group was already collapsed. As I investigate further, this is the quick fix.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Me.Range("B1"), Target) Is Nothing Then
        With Me
            Dim rng As Range
            Set rng = .Columns(1).Find(.Range("B1").Value)

            If Not rng Is Nothing Then
                With rng.Offset(1).EntireRow
                    On Error Resume Next
                    If .OutlineLevel > 1 Then .ShowDetail = False
                End With
            End If
        End With
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Does the above code check the group headers to match B1? I feel like I phrased my initial question badly. The column headers are always present and unchanging. What may change is the number of rows between them and which groups are collapsed or expanded.

Comment: Yes it looks for a cell in Column A that matches `B1`.

Comment: The initial snippet I pieced together works to collapse rows, but if I add or remove rows, it isn't aware and then grabs too many or too few. Is there a way to fix that easily without getting too complicated with arrays and whatnot?

Comment: B1 is intended as a selector for which row groupings to show/hide. "All", "Person A" (who only cares about some headers), "Person B" (who cares about many of the same headers, but some additional and some fewer), "Person C", etc

Comment: Ok I think I understand now. So for example if `B1` is `All`, then I assume everything is expanded. But how are you determining what is expanded if `B1` is `Person A`, for example? Is there list of number codes corresponding to `Person A`, another list for `Person B`, and so on? If so, where is this list or did you plan to hard-code it?

Comment: I edited the original to add some more pictures at the end. Yes, if B1 is "All", I'd want everything expanded. Person A would give me their list, and person B would give me their's, etc. Would it be possible for me to use another sheet for a person to just entry Y or N in a column for each group number? Then I could add more people easily.